# Firebase: observeEventType() only returns one child

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm trying to fetch the child from https://sizzling-heat-9137.firebaseio.com/users, which has 4. This is what I'm doing:

```
  let ref = Firebase(url:"https://sizzling-heat-9137.firebaseio.com/users")

  ref.observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: {
  (snapshot) in
  print("Snapshot: \(snapshot)")
  })
```

According to the guides on Firebase this should give a snapshot of every child (4) and their data, but instead, I get the snapshot for only one child, call it **X** (the first one added but not first in order at `/users`).

When I do `snapshot.childrenCount`I get 7, which is the number of children in the first child **X**. Isn't that supposed to be four which is the total number of children at `/users`?

Am I doing something bad here or what could be the problem? I have tried both on the simulator and my real device.

Comment: have you checked snapshot.value ?

Comment: @AnjaliBhimani Yes and that gives me 7 identical snapshots of all the childs within child X

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change your `observeEventType` from `ChildAdded` to `FIRDataEventType.Value`.

Then you can use your snapshot as dictionnary (for example) :

```
tempUser.firstName = snapshot.value!["firstname"] as! String
```

Comment: I saw I had set the permission rules to nonread of some reason, that was the problem. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score -1):

it will give number of children at the specified url. just check if ur url is pointing to that or the base of the nodes.

Comment: This is not an answer. Please obtain rep and repost as a comment.

Comment: I saw I had set the permission rules to nonread of some reason, that was the problem. Thanks anyway!